# Ubuntu 1904 does not boot from LiveCD on Hyper-V in AMD Ryzen. No problems in 1804

Tags: grub2, virtualization, live-cd, hyper-v, amd-ryzen

When booting 1904 LiveCD from a Hyper-V VM, I get some error messages:

- Spectre V2:Spectre mitigation: LFENCE not serializing, switching to generic retpoline
- Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
- systemd[1]: dev-loop0.device: Failed to set invocation ID for unit: File exists
- systemd[1]: dm-event.socket: Failed to set invocation ID for unit: File exists

After these errors, the Ubuntu splash screen with the red/white five dots stays forever. This happens for any of the 5 first options in the LiveCD GRUB menu, and the only way to regain control is turning off the VM. When selecting "Check disc for defects", I get the same errors, and then "Check finished: no errors found".

The same VM boots LiveCD 1804.2, installs, updates and runs 1804 without a problem.

I tried allocating more and less processors to the VM, enabling and disabling secure boot, enabling and disabling dynamic memory, without any success.

These problems with 1904 only happen in a new PC I built with a X570 chipset and a Ryzen 5 3600X. On a older PC I had, with an Intel Ivy Bridge 3570k and Z77 chipset, 1904 installed OK in Hyper-V. In both cases, the latest version of Windows fully updated was used.

I suppose Hyper-V there is some kind of incompatibility between Ubuntu 1904 and Hyper-V on Ryzen. Does anybody have a similar problem?

Thank you

Comment: Yeah, 19.04 broke something with Ryzen 3. There have been multiple questions about this recently.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments. I thought Hyper-V would add a virtualization layer that abstracted from the actual processor/chipset, but it seems that Hyper-V VMs on Ryzen 3 hosts share the same problems as Ubuntu physically installed on the same platform. Let's hope a future BIOS from MSI will solve this.

Comment: Just an update, a new BIOS Version came out. After installing the new BIOS, the generic retpoline error remained, but the LiveCD boots and installs OK. Thanks for your help, problem solved.